# docker-compose/boot2docker use in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose

I have a `docker-compose.yml` file in my project and I am trying to use it using docker on my linux machine (Ubuntu 14.04).
Can someone shed a light on this how I can use this in my project?
I have installed docker and docker-compose already. Also, I tried using `boot2docker`(however, it's only for Mac and Windows), it did not work.
Please help!

Answer (score 2):

First thing is, you don't need to use `boot2docker` if you are already using the Linux machine. 
Now, if you have already installed `docker` and `docker compose`, just go through this [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) to get started.
In particular, try this [example](https://docs.docker.com/compose/#define-services).